# tag-wiki incorrect, shall I directly edit/or flag

Tags: support, tag-wiki

Some days ago I created [prolog-dif](/questions/tagged/prolog-dif). I now see an entirely unrelated description in its tag. Since I do not see any possibility to flag, what should I do?

- Edit my version by simply removing the existing description? Doesn't this lead to an edit-war?
- Alert the editor somehow?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you're sure that the existing excerpt is incorrect, edit (or suggest an edit if you have <20k reputation) and correct the description. Create a full wiki entry while you're there, if you feel inclined.

In the unlikely event that this leads to an edit war, *that's* the time to flag.

Comment: You can't even flag tag wikis, you'd need a meta discussion.

Comment: Hmm, that's right, @animuson. Well, you can flag tagged questions.

Comment: Yes, flag any post with that tag and use the "it needs ♦ moderator attention" and use the "other" field to describe the problem.

Comment: What exactly would flagging do in the first place? So the moderator makes the change again? That doesn't really solve anything. As far as I'm aware, a tag wiki can't be "locked" like a normal post. If there's two users arguing over what should be in a wiki, a Meta question is probably the only way you're going to solve it.

Comment: @animuson: Meh. A Meta question may build a consensus on the correctness of the content, but it won't fix an "edit war", unless both sides pay attention to the Meta question, and that's unlikely. I see your point about flags - all mods can do is fire off a warning message, if there's abuse in the war.